# LinkedIn hopscotch tutorial - how to change the name of the label?

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api, hopscotch

I am setting up a LinkedIn tour for the website. http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/
It is working fine. But I need to change the text of a done button.
Once I put the following line i18n.doneBtn, the static page comes up but dynamic execution stops and tour does not appear.
Would you have any suggestions on how to fix it? Thanks!

```
       "fnInitComplete": function (){
        $('#accessModal').modal('show');
        {% if request.user.indTutorial %}

            // Define the tour!
        var tour = {
          id: "hello-hopscotch-1",
          steps: [
            {        
              title: "View the Momentum Rankings",
              content: "Algorithms analyze millions of data points to find the fastest growing companies in any industry.",
              target: "tag-page-title",
              width: 450,
              placement: "bottom",
              showCloseButton: true
            },
            {       
              title: "See momentum scores",
              content: "Click on a company to understand the factors that drive their score.",
              //target: "allResultTable",
              target: document.querySelector(".sorting_1"),
              placement: "bottom",
              showCloseButton: true,
              showPrevButton: true,
              width: 450,
              // the title of the done button - next
              i18n.doneBtn: "Next"
            }
          ],

          onEnd: function() {
            window.location.href = '/company/' + $('.my-row').attr('id');
          }
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The i18n property is supposed to be an object, and it's supposed to be at the top level of your tour.

It should look something like this:

```
var tour = {
  id: "hello-hopscotch-1",
  steps: [
    {        
      title: "View the Momentum Rankings",
      content: "Algorithms analyze millions of data points to find the fastest growing companies in any industry.",
      target: "tag-page-title",
      width: 450,
      placement: "bottom",
      showCloseButton: true
    },
    {       
      title: "See momentum scores",
      content: "Click on a company to understand the factors that drive their score.",
      //target: "allResultTable",
      target: document.querySelector(".sorting_1"),
      placement: "bottom",
      showCloseButton: true,
      showPrevButton: true,
      width: 450,
    }
  ],

  onEnd: function() {
    window.location.href = '/company/' + $('.my-row').attr('id');
  },

  i18n: {
    // the title of the done button - next
    doneBtn: "Next"
  }
};
```